# Android Wifi ADB can not connect device

Tags: android

I Want to use plugin Android Wifi ADB for debugging without cable connection.
I installed it in android studio, allowed usb debugging on my mobile phone, connected it to cable and clicked connect.

But all I got is next message: "Unable to connect to device 'SM_G965F'. Make sure that your computer and your device are connected to the same WiFi network."

I am doing is on MAC.
I tried with different mobile phones and different cables and it's always the same. Help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is as follows:

1. Make sure computer and phone are on the same WiFi network
2. Connect phone to PC
3. Run cmd and cd to where you have adb installed.
4. type `adb tcpip XXXX` where XXXX is a port number
5. disconnect phone from PC
6. in the same cmd window, type `adb connect IP:XXXX` where IP is the IP of the phone and XXXX is the same port you chose earlier. To find out your phone's IP simply go to WiFi menu and select the network you are currently connected to. You should then see your network configuration along with the IP of the device.

Comment: Nope. My phone is still not connected and I can not install app from android studio

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this process**

1. Enable USB Debugging

[image]

2. Put it All Together

- Connect your Android device to the computer with a USB cable
- The USB mode must be PTP in order for ADB to work. You can usually change this from   the notification shade
- Make sure to allow USB debugging if a pop-up appears
- Open the platform-tools folder on your computer
- Shift+Right Click and select Open command prompt here
- Type adb devices and hit Enter
- You should see a list of attached devices
- Now you can enter ADB commands!

**Adb restart :-**
adb tcpip 5555

**Adb connect :-**
adb connect 192.168.0.101:5555

**Adb Disconnect :-**
adb disconnect 192.168.0.101:5555

I hope this answer helpful of you.

Thank you

Comment: Nope. My phone is still not connected and I can not install app from android studio

Comment: Please check your network connection. Your both devices mac and phone(SM_G965F) are same network required.

Comment: Yes they are both connected on my home wifi